# Finding Records In Past Few Hours T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

What is the best way to get all records in the past 3 hours by a certain customer? I am not too sure how to set this sql up?

schema

CustID varchar
AddressID varchar
DateCreated datetime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM Customer C
WHERE C.DateCreated > DATEADD(hour, -3, GetDate())
```

- [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
- [GetDate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)

**Edit**: `"past 3 hours by a certain customer"`

```
SELECT C.* 
FROM Customer C
WHERE C.CustID = @CustID
AND C.DateCreated > DATEADD(hour, -3, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 4):

One function you could use is `DATEADD`. The T-SQL below will get all rows from MyTable where MyColumn has a value of greater than or equal to the current date/time minus 3 hours.

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE MyColumn >= DATEADD(hh,-3,GETDATE())
```

You can learn more about DATEADD [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).